# How to use SimpleAdapter in another Activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-activity

I want to use SimpleAdapter in DriverActivity. 
I create activity_list_layout.xml in folder layout like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ColType"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Type"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ColDate"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="Date"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And create activity_driver.xml like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv_driver"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/emptyElement"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="Please add driver"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#525252"
        android:textSize="19.0sp"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

In DriverActivity.java I use custom List view like this.

```
 public void onResume() {

    super.onResume();
    db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    String[] queryColumns = new String[]{"_id", DBHelper.COL_TYPE, DBHelper.COL_OPTION_NAME,DBHelper.COL_DATE };

    cursor = db.query(DBHelper.TABLE_NAME, queryColumns, null,null,
           null,null,null);

    HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();

    String type_name;

    while(cursor.moveToNext())
    {
        type_name=cursor.getColumnName(1);

        map.put("v_type", dbHelper.V_Type(type_name));
        map.put("date", type_name=cursor.getString(4));
        lst_driver.add(map);
    }

    String[] showColumns = new String[]{DBHelper.COL_TYPE, DBHelper.COL_DATE};


    int[] views = new int[] {android.R.id.col, android.R.id.text2};


    adapter = new SimpleAdapter(DriverLicenseActivity.this,lst_driver, android.R.layout.activity_list_layout, showColumns, views);
    lv_driver.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

At new SimpleAdapter android.R.layout.activity_list_layout show error. 
canot resole symbol android.R.layout.activity_list_layout

How to fix problem ?

Comment: remove android. & try with R.layout,activity_list_layout..

Comment: is suggest you use  **RecyclerView** Instead  of  **ListView**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the `android` on your `android.R.layout.activity_list_layout`. It should be like this: `R.layout.activity_list_layout`.

Answer (score 0):

**android.R.** is used for access predefined classes by android SDK (layouts/drawables)

**R** isused for access custom classes  (that means its layouts/drawables imported/created  by user)

that case you should use

```
 SimpleAdapter  adapter = new SimpleAdapter(DriverLicenseActivity.this,lst_driver, R.layout.activity_list_layout, showColumns, views);
```